# How to add Java SE 1.8 dependencies to compile task in gradle?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, program-entry-point

I am running gradle build

what should be written in dependencies for java compile, for Java SE1.8?

also please educate me what are the different ways of adding dependencies in gradle?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you failing?

Answer (score 0):

You can add like this in build.gradle file

```
 apply plugin: 'java'

    java {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```